# Set and Get multi dimensional arraylist to and from a bundle

Tags: android, arraylist, bundle

I have a multi dimensional arraylist and want to pass it to an activity. How do i do this?

My code below is what i have so far...

In my new activity i do stuff and pop the arraylist then bundle it. i then kill my activity and return to previous activity with...

```
        final ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> inviteList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
//populate the arraylist
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra("players", inviteList);
```

My activity (returning from prev activity)

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode,Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 0) {
            //if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // A contact was picked.  Here we will just display it
                // to the user.
                Intent i=getIntent();
                Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
                inviteList = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) i.getSerializableExtra("players");
}
```

resultcode is 0 and requestcode is 0 (what does this tell me?).
this doesn't work - i get null out the other end....

Comment: Rather than asking why don't you try it once and see if there is an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to read your value from the `Activity`'s `Intent`. You should read it from the `data` parameter of your method:

```
inviteList = (ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>) data.getSerializableExtra("players");
```

Comment: It happens to everyone ;)